# match one of two pid's using the processes full path

Tags: windows, powershell, process

I have two identical running processes called `RocketLeague.exe`

I want to store one of the processes PID's in a variable for later use in another command by  matching both processes full file paths.

I have been able to come up with two commands so far that pipe the full path of the processes but can't figure out how to continue the piping of the right PID into a final custom command.

How can I store the correct PID in a variable for use in my custom command?

```
1) Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague' | Format-List -Property Path
2) Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague'
```

Comment: If there are two (2) processes running, how will you determine the correct Id (PID) to save? `Get-Process -Name 'Notepad' | Select-Object -Property Id,ProcessName,CommandLine`

Comment: I was able to piggy back off of this explanation and after a great struggle to understand what you were trying to tell me I think I got it. I will post the answer I was able to achieve and mention your name as the person who helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the feedback from `user:lit` I was able to come up with this solution.

```
$procID = Get-process -Name 'RocketLeague' | Select-Object -Property Id,Path | ForEach-Object {
    If($_.Path -eq 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'){
        Set-Variable -Name 'procSteam' -Value $_.Id; Write-Host $procSteam
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the specific Process that is equal to that Path you can use `Where-Object` or `.Where()` method for filtering. The code would be reduced to:

```
# This:
$procID = (Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague').Where({
    $_.Path -eq 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'
}) | Select-Object -Property Id, Path

# Or this:
$procID = Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague' | Where-Object {
    $_.Path -eq 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\rocketleague\Binaries\Win64\RocketLeague.exe'
} | Select-Object -Property Id, Path
```

And if, for example there is only one of the paths that ends with `Win64\....exe` you can use `.EndsWith()` method:

```
$procID = (Get-Process -Name 'RocketLeague').Where({
    ([string]$_.Path).EndsWith('\Win64\RocketLeague.exe')
}) | Select-Object -Property Id, Path
```